# Real Analysis: Sub sequence Problem

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Show that if $(x_n)$ is unbounded then there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} $ $(1/(x_{n_{k}}))$ $= 0$ .

**Proof:** Suppose $(x_n)$ is an unbounded sequence. Utilizing the Monotone Subsequence Theorem we see that there is a subsequence of  $(x_n)$ that is monotone. Next we will construct our non-decreasing subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$. For our subsequence we will define it as $n_k = 2k$ and pick out every even term in the original sequence. Thus our subsequence should start out as $n_1 = 2, n_2 =4, n_3 = 6, ..., n_k = 2k. $ First note that $n_k  \ge k $ for all $k \in \mathbb N $. Then by induction we see that $n_1 \ge 1$ and $n_k \ge k$ yields the following: $n_{k+1} \gt n_k \ge k$ from which it follows that  $n_{k+1} \ge k+1.$ In terms of our subsequence we see that we obtain the following inequality: $2(k+1) \ge k+1 $ which holds for all $k \in \mathbb N$. Our construction of our subsequence is complete. We now show that the $\lim_{x\to \infty} $ $(1/(x_{n_{k}}))$ $= 0$ . Since $(x_n)$ is a nondecreasing unbounded sequence we know that $(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$. Utilizing the negation of Theorem 3.4.2 we see that $(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ implies that $(x_{n_{k}}) \rightarrow \infty$. Hence taking $\lim_{x\to \infty} $ $(1/(x_{n_{k}})) = 0$ .

For this proof, I'm not sure if I went about it the right way. Also did I correctly define my subsequence and then I was wondering if I need some improvement on showing that $(1/(x_{n_k})) \rightarrow \infty$.  This is my first time writing a proof by constructing a subsequence.

Book used is Introduction to Real Analysis 4th edition by Robert Bartle.

Comment: In the problem, is it assumed that $x_n$ is non-decreasing?   You stated this in your "proof", but it's not stated in the problem.

Comment: Furthermore, how do you know $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded? (Hint) Try to make a more explicit construction without appealing to the monotone subsequence theorem.

Comment: He says $x_n$ is unbounded...

Comment: I think you are mixing up $(x_n)_n$ and some sub-sequence(s). of it.  The premise is  only that $(x_n)_n$ is unbounded, but later you say "since $(x_n)_n$ is monotone,"  .... One way to prove the result is to  let $n(1$) be the least $ n$ such that $|x_n|>1$ and let  $n(j+1)$  be the least $n$ such that $n>n(j)$  and |$x_n|>1+|x_{n(j)}|.$ Then $n(j+1)>n(j)$ and, by induction on $j$ we have  $|1/x_{n(j)}|<1/j.$

Comment: @ DanielWainfleet In order to obtain the sequence $\{n(j)\mid j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, we need some Axiom that is weaker than or equivalent to Axiom of Choice. In general, $\{n(j)\mid j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ cannot be obtained by just using the axioms in ZF. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ can be constructed inductively
(which requires some form of Axiom of Choice) as follows.

The sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ is unbounded, so there exists $n_{1}$
such that $|x_{n_{1}}|\geq1$. Suppose that $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots<n_{k}$
have been chosen such that $|x_{n_{i}}|\geq i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$.
Since $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ is unbounded, for the number $M=|x_{1}|+|x_{2}|+\ldots+|x_{n_{k}}|+(k+1)$,
there exists $j$ such that $|x_{j}|\geq M$. Clearly $j\notin\{1,2,\ldots,n_{k}\}$.
Define $n_{k+1}=j$, then $n_{k}<n_{k+1}$ and $|x_{n_{k+1}}|\geq k+1$.

By some form of Axiom of Choice, we obtain an infinite sequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$
with the property that $n_{k}<n_{k+1}$ and $|x_{n_{k}}|\geq k$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
It is clear that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x_{n_{k}}}=0$.

Comment: Thanks. This makes much more sense.

Comment: You do not need the axiom of choice for a well ordering of a countable set.